# Insert BOM to a CSV File using PERL

Tags: perl, csv, byte-order-mark

Hi I am having a problem with making my CSV file readable.
I am currently trying to do it using PERL. Here's my line of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$infile = @ARGV[0];
$outfile = @ARGV[1];

open(INFILE,"$infile") || die "cannot open input file : $infile : ";

open(OUTFILE,">$outfile") || die "cannot open output file";

$/="undef";

while(<INFILE>)

{

  $temp=$_;

}

close(INFILE);

  print OUTFILE "\x{feff}".$temp;

close(OUTFILE);
```

However, the CSV file is still unreadable.
Is there anything that I can do to insert BOM? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Before we do this, let me tell you that BOMs are an incredible pain in most cases, and should be avoided wherever possible. They are only technically necessary with UTF-16 encodings. The BOM is the Unicode character U+FEFF. It is encoded in UTF-8 as `EF BB BF`, in UTF-16LE as `FF FE`, and UTF-16BE as `FE FF`. It seems you are assuming that your input is UTF-16BE, in that case you could write the bytes directly:

```
open my $in,  "<:raw", $ARGV[0] or die "Can't open $ARGV[0]: $!";
open my $out, ">:raw", $ARGV[1] or die "Can't open $ARGV[1]: $!";

print $out "\xFE\xFF";
while (<$in>) {
    print $out $_;
}
```

But it would probably be better to decode and the encode the output again, and explicitly specify the BOM as a character:

```
open my $in,  "<:encoding(UTF-16BE)", $ARGV[0] or die "Can't open $ARGV[0]: $!";
open my $out, ">:encoding(UTF-16BE)", $ARGV[1] or die "Can't open $ARGV[1]: $!";

print $out "\N{U+FEFF}";
while (<$in>) {
    print $out $_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do, rather than manually inserting a BOM, is [set the output file encoding to whatever it is you need](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html).

Also:

- You are setting the input record separator to the literal string `"undef"`, which is definitely not what you want!  (Although it happens to work as long as undef doesn't appear in the input files).  Remove the quotes there.
- `use warnings; use strict;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this at the top of your code:

```
use open OUT => ':encoding(UTF-16)';
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few answers about your BOM. But here's your code written in more idiomatic Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($infile, $outfile) = @ARGV;

open my $in_fh, $infile or die "cannot open input file : $infile : $!";
open my $out_fh, '>', $outfile or die "cannot open output file: $!";

print $out_fh "\x{feff}";
print $out_fh while <$in_fh>;
```