# setting BOM to Unicode U code UTF8 perl

Tags: perl, csv, unicode, utf-8, hex

This question is similar to others that have been posted before. however trying all combinations nothing is working.

I need to have my excel file read in Unicode Utf8, I am attempting to set my bom:

`my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({binary=>1, eol =>$/}) 
     or die "cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
open my $csvFile, ">:encoding(UTF-8)", "teht.csv" or die "teht.csv: $!";
print($csvFile "\x{FEBBBF}");`

however this gets an errror and says that "0xFEBBBF is not Unicode..."

all information that I have found indicates that the code for utf8 should read 
`print($csvFile "\N{U+FEBBBF}")` or `... "\xFE\xBB\xBF"` or similar.

[Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically) is one source which says this many times.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22711105/6557829 is another source.

So far I have actually been able to get UTF-16 to work with the same print statement: `print($csvFile "\N{U+FEFF}");` however that is more space than I mean to use. 
Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: BOM is U+FEFF, not U+FEBBBF.

Comment: @ikegami U+FEFF is the code for utf16 not for utf8

Comment: U+FEFF means "Unicode Code Point FEFF", and it has nothing to do with UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BOM is U+FEFF, not U+FEBBBF. Replace

```
"\x{FEBBBF}"
```

with any one of following:

```
chr(0xFEFF)
"\x{FEFF}"
"\N{U+FEFF}"
"\N{BOM}"
```

This will create a string with a single character (`FEFF`), which `print` will encode using UTF-8 as requested (`EF BB BF`).

Comment: that should be for utf-16 coding, but I am looking for utf8 I was saying how that works when I do either of the first two options that you reccomended, however I mean to use 8 bits not 16

Comment: Did you try it? You would have seen that you are mistaken. See the added paragraph.